# React-Table open SubComponent from state

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I would like to create some kind of routing for my `react-table` so that as soon as the user opens a row (using `SubComponent`), the URL should change accordingly. So when the user refreshes the page, bookmarks it, or sends it to someone else, the same row should be expanded.

However, I did not find a way to specify if a row is opened or not.

Answer (score 0):

I got it...

```
 <ReactTable
    ...
    defaultExpanded={{
      2: true,
    }}
  />
```